# Can emacs be configured to support more terminals?

Tags: term

I recently switched from [rxvt-unicode](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/rxvt-unicode) to [st](https://st.suckless.org). This means I went from `$TERM=rxvt-unicode-256color` to `$TERM=st-256color`.

I'm happy with the switch and want to continue to use `st`. However, I quickly noticed that emacs was not rendering my colors appropriately. After some googling, I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7617458/terminal-emacs-colors-only-work-with-term-xterm-256color/49364532#49364532). Following mndrix's advice, I added

```
(add-to-list 'term-file-aliases
    '("st-256color" . "xterm-256color"))
```

to my `.emacs`. This solved the problem. However, my start time is now *really* slow.

Now I'm wondering if there is another solution. On my system, the directory `/usr/share/emacs/26.2/lisp/term` has some `el.gz` and `elc` files corresponding to different terminals. For instance, this directory has `xterm.el.gz` and `xterm.elc` in it. I'm guessing that the fundamental issue is that this directory does not have `st.el.gz` and `st.elc`. Is it possible to add this support? If so, how might one go about this configuration?

Comment: "However, my start time is now really slow." seems like a very unexpected consequence of setting that term alias.  *How* much slower are we talking?

Comment: @phils Like a hard five count. I don't know how to rigorously convey this information which is why I put effort into phrasing this question in a way so that I hoped people wouldn't interpret it as an XY question. I gave motivation for my question but the question stands alone apart from the motivation.

Comment: Can you confirm that `env TERM=xterm-256color emacs` is just as slow?  What about with `emacs -Q` instead of `emacs` ?

Comment: "I gave motivation for my question but the question stands alone apart from the motivation." -- If you're not looking for solutions to the slowness (and it's not obvious that a `st.el` library should behave any differently), it's probably best to remove that context from the question as, despite your efforts, it did seem rather like an XY question.  It's probably also more a feature-request to submit with `M-x report-emacs-bug`.

Comment: https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=33182

Comment: @philis There's no winning asking questions here. Asking a question without motivation inevitably results in someone asking *why* you're asking the question. Adding motivation inevitably results in someone assuming it's an XY problem. The time delay is obviously an issue and I tried to diagnose it by observing that st is absent from the `/lisp/term` directory.

Comment: Well, I wouldn't say there's *no* winning -- I think you've acquired relevant and useful information :) -- but I know what you mean; it can be hard to phrase things in a way that all readers will interpret the same way.  Now that there's confirmation of the link between `xterm.el` and the slowness under `st`, you could always rephrase the question slightly to emphasise that the actual question truly is directly relevant to the observed problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is Emacs [bug 33182](https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=33182).

The 5-second delay is confirmed in that bug report.

No `st.el` library is provided in that bug report at this point; but that would be the sensible place to follow up.

You could start by looking at the existing term libraries and README file:

- https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs.git/tree/lisp/term
- https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs.git/plain/lisp/term/README

I would suggest looking into those, and see whether you can come up with something which works, and then following up the bug report.

Eli's comment in that bug also points us to these:

```
xterm-extra-capabilities is a variable defined in `xterm.el'.
Its value is `check'

Documentation:
Whether Xterm supports some additional, more modern, features.
If nil, just assume that it does not.
If `check', try to check if it does.
If a list, assume that the listed features are supported, without checking.

The relevant features are:
  modifyOtherKeys  -- if supported, more key bindings work (e.g., "\C-,")
  reportBackground -- if supported, Xterm reports its background color
  getSelection     -- if supported, Xterm yanks text from the X selection
  setSelection     -- if supported, Xterm saves killed text to the X selection
```

and

```
xterm-query-timeout is a variable defined in `xterm.el'.
Its value is 2

Documentation:
Seconds to wait for an answer from the terminal.
Can be nil to mean "no timeout".
```